# Desencriptar valor en C#

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo un dato encriptado Encriptado desde `Sql` usando `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE`, ahora en `C#`, para poder mostrarlo como lo puedo DESCENCRIPTAR, mi código es el siguiente:

```
 foreach (var item in query.ToList())
            {
                Empleado items = new Empleado();
                list.Add(new Empleado()
                {
                    _id = item.id.ToString(),
                    _nombre = item.Nombre.ToString(),
                    _apellido = item.APELLIDO.ToString(),
                    _correo = item.CORREO.ToString(),
                    _contrasena = item.CONTRASENA.ToString() //Dato Encriptado
                   
                }
                );
            }
            return list;
```

CONTRASENA me regresa un array y en cada posicion diferentes datos, imagino que es lo encriptado, como puedo hacer que cuando guarde en la lista, lo descencripte y lo guarde con el dato original, intente con esto pero me salieron letras chinas

```
_contrasena = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(item.CONTRASENA)
```

Comment: puedes usar  `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` desde sql para obtener el valor desencriptado

Comment: Lo se pero como seria en c#, necesito mostrar el dato en un input

Comment: Porque se quiere complicar la vida haciendolo desde C#???  Simplemente en el select  utilize el DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE  como le indico el colega L.Ronquillo. Y si necesita que le llegue encriptado por alguna razón entonces Desencriptelo primero en sql con DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE  , luego encriptelo con md5 o alguna encriptación que pueda utiilizar desde c# . Algo como esto : CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'email@dot.com'), 2)

Comment: MIi consulta es a traves de Entity F. Como seria en ese caso,si hay palabras como DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE  que no reconoce como tal